# What is the best method for storing values in a web form?

Tags: cookies

**Brief (Simplified)**

- I need to create a form to be embedded within the Header (Navigation bar) of a website. The form will have an "Update/Save" button. (Easy bit)
- I need those values to stay in the fields once the "Update/Save" button has been pressed, regardless of moving around the website. (Hard bit)
- Would be preferable if the stored values stayed valid for 30 days from last "Update/Save"

**Question**

I've read up on using cookies to store the values. *However, I've never used cookies before.* Are there better methods to achieve this - or could someone share any insight into creating forms with cookies, as Google hasn't really given me any solutions on the subject (not good ones anyway)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is JS an option? How about using this (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library then?

Comment: Thanks @Greg, this looks pretty useful - I'll have a read through the documentation

Comment: As a sitenote: If you are in the EU and you want to store personal information in the cookies you probably need to get the users consent regarding to the EU privacy directive